# System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message in service bus

Tags: azure, access-control, servicebus

My service was working fine and now I am getting this exception and service stop working:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message

searching internet shows some code problem but my code was working find and now it just stop working, not sure what is the problem..

stacktrace

Exception thrown during execution: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party.

See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

> Server stack trace: 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at NewWcfService.IExternalStringService.Reverse(String value) at WcfWebClient._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\projects\ACSSamples\Microsoft\WebServices\Acs2UsernameBindingSample\WcfWebClient\Default.aspx.cs:line 55

Comment: Would u please provide Stack trace for this exception?

Comment: This is a security related problem with your Access Control service. Have you changed any certificate recently which cause this service to break? Check your certificates or anything that depend on security because if you haven't changed any code then this could be the cause.

Comment: yes. i use a test cert with my endpoint which is expired. i sould get a notification for expired cert that but no error message. I made new cert and changed it and problem gone. thanks though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly is is a security related problem with your Access Control service rather then platform specific because there is no code change.

Have you changed any certificate recently which cause this service to break? Check your certificates or anything that depend on security because if you haven't changed any code then changes in security setting could be the cause of your problem.